# python err: Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors

I get error `UnboundLocal: Local variable T referenced before assignment`, however it's not like that:

```
import ...
T = 0

def do_something():
    do_something_else(T) # err at this line
T += 1

def do_something_else(t):
    print t

do_something()
```

That is how my code looks, so it is not reference before assignment. (correct me if I am wrong) What's wrong?

Comment: I don't get any error

Comment: are you using ipython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `T` as global variable:

```
def do_something():
    global T # <--------------
    do_something_else(T) # err at this line
    T += 1
```